# Flutter build for plugin fails, class file not found

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm developing a plugin using Snapchat's SDK, it runs fine on iOS, however when compiling and running on Android I keep getting an error:

```
/Users/jnbra/Projects/snapkit/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:17: error: cannot access LoginStateController
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.jacobbrasil.snapkit.SnapkitPlugin());
                          ^
class file for com.snapchat.kit.sdk.core.controller.LoginStateController not found
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The class is accessible and downloaded and I can view the source code for it in Android Studio. I've tried changing SDK versions, clearing my Gradle cache, and a few others but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi,Have you tried to file ->Invalidate/cache and restart and then rebuild project,in android studio? Sometimes this error occurs when project has not detected the new resource.

Comment: Were you able to get any solution?

Comment: Any update about this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `implementation` for adding any dependency?

If yes, try replacing it with `api`. Not sure but it worked for me.

Example:

Replace

```
implementation 'com.github.niraj-prajapati:UPIPayments:1.1.4'
```

with

```
api 'com.github.niraj-prajapati:UPIPayments:1.1.4'
```

Comment: Does this apply to local AAR files too? I have it as `implementation(name:'package_name', ext:'aar')` but facing the same issue in the question

Comment: @a7md0 , not sure about `.aar` file. but `.jar` can be used same way `api files('libs/jarFileName.jar')`.
You can try replacing `implementation` with `api` and let me know if it helps. 
Till the time i'll also be checking when i get some time.

Comment: It's working perfectly, thank you. For reference it's `api(name:'package_name', ext:'aar')` now